# Is there a way to start VS Code keybinding with a comma?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

Is there a way to make a key-binding in VS Code that starts with `,` or `;` as it is in vim?

Currently I have it in `settings.json` like this:

```
  "vim.leader": ",",
  "vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
        { "before": [ "<leader>", "n" ],          "commands": [ ":nohl" ] },
  ],
```

It works there. But I'd like to have all my keybindings in `keybindings.json`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... yes?

```json
{
    // chord (press comma, release, press n)
    "key": ", n", // or "[Comma] n"
    "command": "cursorUp"
},
{
    // (press comma, press n, release)
    "key": ",+n", // or "[Comma]+n"
    "command": "cursorUp"
}
```

But if you use the chord method, you'd need to create some other binding to insert a comma... VS Code doesn't have a thing to make chords time out and then fallback to inserting whatever incomplete parts of the chord were pressed.

Comment: Well, thinking of it I found it is easier for me to map only `Ctrl+,` to insert `,` and use `,` as leader key as I used to do in vim. Here is how I did it: `{ "key": "ctrl+,", "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet", "when": "editorTextFocus", "args": {"snippet": ","} },`
Is there a simpler way?